# Is there any extention for mozilla for simulate dial up?

Tags: web, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools, development-environment

I want to simulate my project in low speed internet connection so i search a extension or

software ...

Is there any extension for Mozilla or chrome to test sites with low speed internet...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159787/is-there-anyway-to-throttle-connection-speed-bandwidth-using-modern-browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about any extension, however can't you just use an application to limit your browsers speed? For example: [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).